# grep loop returning output per file not per search term

Tags: bash, loops, grep

I have a directory of multiple files. I want to search all of those files for the same keywords and tell me whether or not each keyword is present in every file in the directory.

I've put the keywords into an array, and this has gotten the script to at least run all the way through to the final echo commands (see below). But I don't think it's looping the grep command the way I want it to.

```
DATA_DIR=/directorypath
SEARCH1="sulfonamide"
SEARCH2="resistance"
declare -a LIST_STRINGS=(${SEARCH1} ${SEARCH2})

cd ${DATA_DIR}
LIST_FILES=`ls -1 */*.faa`

for file in ${LIST_FILES};do                ##loop command for every file in the list
    echo "Filename is ${file}"
    for item in ${LIST_STRINGS[*]};do       ##loop command for every search item in the array list
        grep -qi ${item} ${file}            ##search current file for current search item. q to return 0 status if a match is found. i to ignore upper/lower case
        
        if [ $? == "0" ];then
            echo "${item} found!"
        else                   
            echo "${item} not found"
        fi
    done
done
```

At the moment the output is constantly telling me that it can't find either of the items in the array in any of the files. My output looks like this (repeated for every file in the directory):

```
Filename is path/file.faa
sulfonamide not found
resistance not found
```

However, I know this is wrong because I have checked the files manually and found that SEARCH2 is present but SEARCH1 isn't.

So is the grep command returning a non-0 status because it can't find both terms? How do I get it to perform a renewed grep search for each item in the array of strings?

I have tried switching the order of the terms and scanning only one file. The result is the same - the output tells me that neither term could be found, when in reality one of them was present.

Comment: You can avoid looping through every element of the array by using grep -F and so grep -F "$(echo ${LIST_STRIMGS[@]} | xargs printf "%s\n")" ${file}

Comment: Soooo you want `grep -f <(printf "%s\n" "${LIST_STRINGS[@]}") --include '*.faa' *`?